# Camel is not running in with Jboss fuse 6

Tags: xml, maven, jboss

I am getting error 
**Error occurred while running main from: org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main when i run my blueprint.xml**
My blueprint.xml looks like this:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
   http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring/camel-spring.xsd">

<camelContext xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
<route>
<from uri="file:input?delete=true"/>
<to uri="file:output"/>
</route>
</camelContext>

</beans>
```

And my pom.xml looks like this:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0   http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.ericsson</groupId>
<artifactId>mm-demo</artifactId>
<packaging>bundle</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

<name>Camel Blueprint Route</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <fabric8.profile>file-collection</fabric8.profile>
    <fabric8.parentProfiles>feature-camel</fabric8.parentProfiles>
    <fabric8.features>camel</fabric8.features>
</properties>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
        <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
        <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>release.fusesource.org</id>
        <name>FuseSource Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>ea.fusesource.org</id>
        <name>FuseSource Community Early Access Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://repo.fusesource.com/nexus/content/groups/ea</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Testing & Camel Plugin -->
</dependencies>

<build>
    <defaultGoal>install</defaultGoal>

    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- to generate the MANIFEST-FILE of the bundle -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.7</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>bundle-manifest</id>
                    <phase>process-classes</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>file-collection</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>com.ericsson.file.collection.*</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <!-- to run the example using mvn camel:run -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.15.1.redhat-620133</version>
            <configuration>
                <useBlueprint>true</useBlueprint>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>io.fabric8</groupId>
            <artifactId>fabric8-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.redhat-133</version>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings 
                only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself. -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-bundle-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.3.7,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>manifest</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

 </project>
```

I am getting error like this:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Camel Blueprint Route 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) > test-compile @ mm-demo >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ mm-demo ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ mm-demo ---
 [INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-bundle-plugin:2.3.7:manifest (bundle-manifest) @ mm-demo ---
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ mm-demo ---
 [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
 [INFO] Copying 0 resource
 [INFO] 
 [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ mm-demo ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) < test-compile @ mm-demo <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) @ mm-demo ---
[INFO] Using org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main to initiate a CamelContext
[INFO] Starting Camel ...
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] MainSupport                    INFO  Apache Camel 2.15.1.redhat-620133 starting
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator starting
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator started
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  No quiesce support is available, so blueprint components will not participate in quiesce operations
 [         Blueprint Extender: 1] BlueprintContainerImpl         INFO  Bundle file-collection is waiting for namespace handlers       [http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans, http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring]
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  Test bundle headers: Bundle-ManifestVersion=2, Bundle-Name=System Bundle, Bundle-SymbolicName=de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework, Bundle-Vendor=kalpatec, Bundle-Version=0.2.1
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
  [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [8], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [8], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.packageadmin.PackageAdmin], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint [6], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.TypeConverterLoader], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactListener, org.apache.felix.fileinstall.ArtifactInstaller], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [30], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-spring [8], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-spring
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedServiceFactory], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [30], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.DataFormatResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.ComponentResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.url.URLStreamHandlerService], bundle: org.apache.felix.fileinstall [30], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.fileinstall
  [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.proxy.ProxyManager], bundle: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl [20], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.proxy.impl
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainer], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.framework.hooks.bundle.EventHook], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.startlevel.StartLevel], bundle: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework [0], symbolicName: de.kalpatec.pojosr.framework
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.camel.spi.LanguageResolver], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-core [3], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-core
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.osgi.service.cm.ConfigurationAdmin], bundle: org.apache.felix.configadmin [29], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.configadmin
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.felix.cm.PersistenceManager], bundle: org.apache.felix.configadmin [29], symbolicName: org.apache.felix.configadmin
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.services.ParserService], bundle: org.apache.aries.blueprint [18], symbolicName: org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           WARN  ServiceReference: [org.apache.aries.blueprint.NamespaceHandler], bundle: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint [6], symbolicName: org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
 [mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle file-collection
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.aries.blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] BlueprintExtender              INFO  Destroying BlueprintContainer for bundle org.apache.camel.camel-blueprint
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator stopping
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] Activator                      INFO  Camel activator stopped
[mel.test.blueprint.Main.main()] CamelBlueprintHelper           INFO    Deleting work directory target/bundles/1446540879356
 [ERROR] *************************************
 [ERROR] Error occurred while running main from:   org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main
 [ERROR] 
  java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
     at   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
     at   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.camel.maven.RunMojo$1.run(RunMojo.java:488)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Gave up waiting for service   (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext)
at   org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:240)
    at  org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.CamelBlueprintHelper.getOsgiService(CamelBlueprintHelper.java:202)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.doStart(Main.java:104)
    at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:150)
    at org.apache.camel.main.MainSupport.run(MainSupport.java:354)
    at org.apache.camel.test.blueprint.Main.main(Main.java:81)
    ... 6 more
   [ERROR] *************************************
   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 40.261 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-03T14:25:10+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 19M/260M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.camel:camel-maven-plugin:2.15.1.redhat-620133:run (default-cli) on project mm-demo: null: MojoExecutionException: InvocationTargetException: Gave up waiting for service (objectClass=org.apache.camel.CamelContext) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: by mistake i posted wrong pom.xml but now its right

Answer (score 0):

Add the following plugin repository in your pom.xml:

```
<pluginRepository>
  <id>redhat</id>
  <url>https://maven.repository.redhat.com/ga/</url>
  <releases>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
  </releases>
</pluginRepository>
```